# Optional method argument by passing Unit as type to generic trait

Tags: scala

Say I have a trait:

```
trait Foo[T] {
    val x: T => Any
}
```

Now I want to make it possible to omit the function argument, by making it a unit:

```
class Bar extends Foo[Unit] {
  override val x = () => "Hello"
}
```

The above code does not compile ("x overrides nothing").

Is there a way to make this work in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the misunderstanding here is that `()` is not a value of type `Unit` but instead represents an empty argument list. So

```
() => "Hello"
```

is a unary function without argument. However, your trait expects a function that takes one argument of type `Unit`.

If you remove the `override`, which isn't necessary here, you will get a compiler error, that will point you in that direction.
If you then replace the `()` with a wildcard `_` or better yet `(_: Unit)`, your code will compile.

```
trait Foo[T] {
    val x: T => Any
}

trait Bar extends Foo[Unit] {
  val x: Unit => Any = (_: Unit) => "Hello"
}
```